# How make a buttons to fill column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using **bootstrap 3** in my project.

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <input type="button" name="name" value="butten 1" />
    <input type="button" name="name" value="butten 2" />
    <input type="button" name="name" value="butten 3" />
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a class="btn btn-primary">butten 1</a>
    <a  class="btn btn-primary">butten 2</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary">butten 3</a>
</div>
```

Here how it look in view:

[image]

As you can see in view I have two rows of buttons.

My question is why the width of upper buttons row is not fill all width of the parent row as the second buttons row?

Comment: You should consider looking into Bootstrap's `grid` system. That will do what you want. Use columns to split up your buttons the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

The classes on the buttons in the second group give the buttons their styling. Specifically, `btn`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't attach the bootstrap classes for styling buttons to the `<button>` elements in the first group, so they are using the default browser styling. You should be adding the classes like so:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="name" value="butten 1" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="name" value="butten 2" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="name" value="butten 3" />
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a class="btn btn-primary">butten 1</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary">butten 2</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary">butten 3</a>
</div>
```

See [the docs here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) for details.

Comment: I try it but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong input classes for your buttons.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oa9wj80x/7/

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-4" name="name" value="butten 1" /> 
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-4" name="name" value="butten 2" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-4" name="name" value="butten 3" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a class="btn btn-primary">butten 1</a>
    <a  class="btn btn-primary">butten 2</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary">butten 3</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: @BhargavRao go ahead and downvote the answer then, if "wrong input classes for your buttons" is not clear enough and you think you can better explain it, go ahead and edit my answer.

Comment: Add a sentence as to why you have asked the OP to use `"btn btn-primary col-xs-4"` there and what will it actually do. A single extra line will be fine.